# How to login user with otp after sign out using firebase in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have created an android app where I sign up user with otp verification and store user with email and password details in firebase.
but when user logout in login section I try to login user with email and password but at a time firebase thrown error user not found.
I sign up user in firebase with otp verification method and login user with authsigninwithemailandpassword method of firebase.
Here is my code:

I pass value to the otpverification.java file
RegisterPage.java :-

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OtpVerificationPage.class);
i.putExtra("phoneNumber", binding.ccp.getFullNumberWithPlus());
i.putExtra("userName", binding.userNameET.getText().toString());
i.putExtra("userEmail", binding.emailET.getText().toString());
i.putExtra("userPassword", binding.passwordET.getText().toString());
startActivity(i);
Toast.makeText(RegisterPage.this, "Please Verify With Otp", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

OtpVerification.java

```
private void sendOtp() {
    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            userPhoneNo,
            60,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            OtpVerificationPage.this,
            new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(OtpVerificationPage.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String verificationId, @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                    super.onCodeSent(verificationId, forceResendingToken);
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    getbackEndOtp = verificationId;
                    Toast.makeText(OtpVerificationPage.this, "Otp Sent Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
    );
}
```

Send otp method now verification method :-

```
if (getbackEndOtp != null) {
    //Check User otp with google otp
    PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(getbackEndOtp, userEnterdOtp);
    //Second progress dialog display
    progressDialog1.show();

    //Authenticate user here
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

            //Generate User with user model class
            FirebaseUser userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            UserModel userModel = new UserModel();
            userModel.setUserId(userId.getUid());
            userModel.setUserName(userName);
            userModel.setUserEmail(userEmail);
            userModel.setUserContactNo(userPhoneNo);
            userModel.setUserPassword(userPassword);


            //If user authentication task is successful this method run
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                progressDialog1.dismiss();
                        database.getReference()
                                .child("Users")
                                .child(userId.getUid())
                                .setValue(userModel)
                                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(OtpVerificationPage.this, MainActivity.class);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                        finishAffinity();
                                    }
                                });

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(OtpVerificationPage.this, "Please enter otp which send to your mobile no", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });//Authentication Method Complete here
}
```

Otp verification completely works and store user data in firebase
[Data store completely with in realtime database.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGdIE.png)

Now problem arise after user logout verification with email and password not work
but i already store user with email and password.

LoginActivity.java

```
//Firebase
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    //Check User
    binding.signInBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            progressDialog.show();
            String email = binding.emailET.getText().toString();
            String password =  binding.passwordET.getText().toString();
            auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginPage.this, MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(LoginPage.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    });
```

Now when i click on sign in button this error arise:

[image: error photo]

how to solve this error?

Comment: Are you sure that the user exists? Can you see that in the Firebase console?

Comment: Yes u can see that in last photo

Comment: No, in the Firebase console, in the authentication section, not in the Realtime Database.